# How to find bootstrap js individual plugin's dependencies?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I removed bootstrap.js from my project and included only `carousel.js`. But the carousel doesn't work properly now. As I read through [bootstrap.js docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-overview), they suggested that indivdual plugins depend upon each other:

> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs.

I read whole of the docs but nowhere is the dependencies of individual plugins is mentioned so my question is how do I find all the dependencies of a particular bootstrap.js plugin?

Comment: jQuery is one dependancy

Comment: @Krishna9960 Wait I add a proof demo where jquery is not the only dependency.

Comment: I didn't said only , I said it is one of them

Comment: @Krishna9960 Could you tell what are other dependencies or where can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is Bootstrap's only required dependency. The other dependencies that the documentation refers to are normally part of `bootstrap.min.js` but can be included (or not included) in the build - see here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#plugins

If you only want the Carousel plugin, toggle all the check boxes in the plugins section, and select "Carousel Functionality." Then toggle all the check boxes in the LESS section, and select "Carousel." At the bottom of the screen you can click "Compile and Download" to get your custom build including only the Carousel stuff.

Comment: Could you tell which part of bootstrap.min.js is required for `carousel.js`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you customize the download, `bootstrap.min.js` is built specifically for the Carousel feature.

Comment: I cannot use the official bootstrap custom build because I have modified carousel.js to have user defined transition speed. I think I have found the dependency. Let me verify.

Comment: The `bootstrap.js` that is included with the full Bootstrap download is well commented - you could technically modify that file and then minify it yourself. Just take a look at what the custom build gives you to have an idea of what to take out and what to leave in your modified file.

Additionally, Carousel already provides a user-defined transition speed: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-options (see `interval`)

Comment: `interval` is for time difference between individual slides. I have modified it to change the speed at which the slide moves. I am writing the answer. The dependency is transition.js.

Comment: Ahhh, THAT transition speed. Got it. Glad you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the downvotes on my question but any how I appreaciate J.Titus and Krishna tried to help me. The dependency other than jquery for `carousel.js` is `transition.js`. Although I figured that out myself I would appreciate if someone could mention a comprehensiv list of dependencies for each bootstrap js plugin.

**Proof, carousel.js without transition.js**

```js
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: carousel.js v3.3.7
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element)
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
    this.options     = options
    this.paused      = null
    this.sliding     = null
    this.interval    = null
    this.$active     = null
    this.$items      = null

    this.options.keyboard && this.$element.on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))

    this.options.pause == 'hover' && !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) && this.$element
      .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
      .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
  }

  Carousel.VERSION  = '3.3.7'

  Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 600

  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true,
    keyboard: true
  }

  Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    if (/input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break
      case 39: this.next(); break
      default: return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = false)

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
    this.$items = item.parent().children('.item')
    return this.$items.index(item || this.$active)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemForDirection = function (direction, active) {
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(active)
    var willWrap = (direction == 'prev' && activeIndex === 0)
                || (direction == 'next' && activeIndex == (this.$items.length - 1))
    if (willWrap && !this.options.wrap) return active
    var delta = direction == 'prev' ? -1 : 1
    var itemIndex = (activeIndex + delta) % this.$items.length
    return this.$items.eq(itemIndex)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
    var that        = this
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active'))

    if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

    if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () { that.to(pos) }) // yes, "slid"
    if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

    return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', this.$items.eq(pos))
  }

  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
      this.cycle(true)
    }

    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('next')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('prev')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    var $next     = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active)
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var that      = this

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

    var relatedTarget = $next[0]
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    })
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.sliding = true

    isCycling && this.pause()

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }) // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
      $next.addClass(type)
      $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction)
      $next.addClass(direction)
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
          that.sliding = false
          setTimeout(function () {
            that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
          }, 0)
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION)
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active')
      $next.addClass('active')
      this.sliding = false
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel')
      var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      var action  = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
      else if (action) data[action]()
      else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.carousel

  $.fn.carousel             = Plugin
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


  // CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.carousel = old
    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

  var clickHandler = function (e) {
    var href
    var $this   = $(this)
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) // strip for ie7
    if (!$target.hasClass('carousel')) return
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

    Plugin.call($target, options)

    if (slideIndex) {
      $target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide]', clickHandler)
    .on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide-to]', clickHandler)

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
      var $carousel = $(this)
      Plugin.call($carousel, $carousel.data())
    })
  })

}(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**Proof, carousel.js with transition.js**

```js
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: transition.js v3.3.7
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#transitions
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (Shoutout: http://www.modernizr.com/)
  // ============================================================

  function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
      }
    }

    return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)
  }

  // http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions
  $.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = function (duration) {
    var called = false
    var $el = this
    $(this).one('bsTransitionEnd', function () { called = true })
    var callback = function () { if (!called) $($el).trigger($.support.transition.end) }
    setTimeout(callback, duration)
    return this
  }

  $(function () {
    $.support.transition = transitionEnd()

    if (!$.support.transition) return

    $.event.special.bsTransitionEnd = {
      bindType: $.support.transition.end,
      delegateType: $.support.transition.end,
      handle: function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(this)) return e.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments)
      }
    }
  })

}(jQuery);



/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: carousel.js v3.3.7
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element)
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
    this.options     = options
    this.paused      = null
    this.sliding     = null
    this.interval    = null
    this.$active     = null
    this.$items      = null

    this.options.keyboard && this.$element.on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))

    this.options.pause == 'hover' && !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) && this.$element
      .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
      .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
  }

  Carousel.VERSION  = '3.3.7'

  Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 600

  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true,
    keyboard: true
  }

  Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    if (/input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break
      case 39: this.next(); break
      default: return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = false)

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
    this.$items = item.parent().children('.item')
    return this.$items.index(item || this.$active)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemForDirection = function (direction, active) {
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(active)
    var willWrap = (direction == 'prev' && activeIndex === 0)
                || (direction == 'next' && activeIndex == (this.$items.length - 1))
    if (willWrap && !this.options.wrap) return active
    var delta = direction == 'prev' ? -1 : 1
    var itemIndex = (activeIndex + delta) % this.$items.length
    return this.$items.eq(itemIndex)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
    var that        = this
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active'))

    if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

    if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () { that.to(pos) }) // yes, "slid"
    if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

    return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', this.$items.eq(pos))
  }

  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
      this.cycle(true)
    }

    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('next')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('prev')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    var $next     = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active)
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var that      = this

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

    var relatedTarget = $next[0]
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    })
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.sliding = true

    isCycling && this.pause()

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }) // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
      $next.addClass(type)
      $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction)
      $next.addClass(direction)
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
          that.sliding = false
          setTimeout(function () {
            that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
          }, 0)
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION)
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active')
      $next.addClass('active')
      this.sliding = false
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel')
      var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      var action  = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
      else if (action) data[action]()
      else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.carousel

  $.fn.carousel             = Plugin
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


  // CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.carousel = old
    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

  var clickHandler = function (e) {
    var href
    var $this   = $(this)
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) // strip for ie7
    if (!$target.hasClass('carousel')) return
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

    Plugin.call($target, options)

    if (slideIndex) {
      $target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide]', clickHandler)
    .on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide-to]', clickHandler)

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
      var $carousel = $(this)
      Plugin.call($carousel, $carousel.data())
    })
  })

}(jQuery);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```